# Ошибка программы при выполнении scanf

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin

Выполняю простейший базовый пример из учебника "Программирование на С для новичков" МакГрата:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char letter;
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter any one keyboard character: ");
    scanf("%c",letter);
    printf("Enter two integers separated by a space: ");
    scanf("%d %d", num1, num2);
    printf("Numbers input: %d and %d \n", num1, num2);
    printf("Letter input: %c", letter);
    printf("Stored at: %p \n", &letter);
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции проблем нет (использую Tiny C Compiler под Windows 8.1). При запуске исполняемого файла получаю первый запрос на ввод одиночного символа. Ввожу символ и после нажатия на Enter получаю стандартное окно аварийного прекращения программы без указания причин (или хотя бы каких намеков) проблемы.

При компиляции GCC под Cygwin происходит подобное, правда без окна аварийного завершения программы - она просто отваливается.

```
cygdrive/y/Programming/C>$ gcc temp.c -o temp.exe

cygdrive/y/Programming/C>$ ./temp.exe
Enter any one keyboard character: f

cygdrive/y/Programming/C>$
```

Собственно кроме мыслей о том, что что-то не так с самой функцией `scanf` при работе с виндовым стандартным вводом, в голову не приходит.

UPD: попробовал с другими форматами и типами переменных - то же самое - вылет с ошибкой.

Comment: Нормальный (современный) gcc должен писать warning, что-то вроде -- `t.c:13:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]`

Comment: `cygdrive/y/Programming/C>$ gcc --version`    
`gcc (GCC) 5.4.0`

Comment: Странно, у меня `gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)` показывает (насколько помню, в 4-ке уже показывало)

Comment: Кстати, программа (если добавить нужные `&`) в Linux нормально работает (в `"Letter input: %c"` в конце `\n`, похоже, тоже пропущен)

Comment: Ключевое слово "в Linux". В моем окружении поведение программы отличается. См комментарии к первому ответу

Comment: Поставьте хотя бы виртуалку (а лучше вообще забудьте про винду)

Comment: А вам не приходило в голову, что не все на этом сайте обязательно программисты по профессии? Да и далеко не все из области IT даже. А большинству из таких пользователей работодатель диктует, какое окружение работник может использовать на рабочем месте. Если вы предлагаете забыть про винду, то значит вы готовы оплачивать мою работу вместо работодателя?

Comment: Вы меня просто заинтересовали. Проверил в 7-й винде `gcc 3.4.5 mingw-vista special r3` (другой под руками нет) из стандартного cmd окошка. Все работает, как и в Linux без всяких fflush(stdin) (за исключением warning, если убрать `&` в scanf). Что у вас за среда?

Comment: Windows 8.1 x64, gcc 5.4.0 под последней версией cygwin x64. Проверяю повторной компиляцией tiny c compiler 0.9.26 x64. Код пишется без использования IDE и автоматической сборки средствами Notepad++. Код использовал не только свой (с ошибками), но и корректно работающий у других. Явных причин иного поведения программы, кроме какого-то шаманства с директивами препроцессора в библиотеке stdio, не вижу.

Comment: Виной странного поведения оказался антивирус. Не знаю что и зачем он делал, но после добавления папки с исходниками в список исключения, работа `scanf()` стала стабильной и без неожиданностей.

Comment: И такое бывает. Напишите свой ответ про антивирус (другим участникам в будущем м.б. полезно) и как только система позволит, примите (отметьте галкой) его.

Comment: 95-99% программной разработки в мире делается под Windows. Подавляющая масса повседневной разработки ПО *для Linux* делается именно *под Windows*. Сам Linux используется лишь для чистовой сборки и QA. Поэтому не ясно о каком "забудьте про Винду" может идти речь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обобщу то, что удалось выяснить в обсуждениях с товарищами @Harry и @avp.

В исходном коде, опубликованном в книге, действительно имеется ошибка. В качестве второго аргумента функции `scanf()` передается не переменная, а указатель на нее. То есть корректный код должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char letter;
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter any one keyboard character: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    printf("Enter two integers separated by a space: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    printf("Numbers input: %d and %d \n", num1, num2);
    printf("Letter input: %c", letter);
    printf("Stored at: %p \n", &letter);
    return 0;
}
```

Дальнейшие проблемы с работой функции `scanf()` (пропуск второго вызова), скорее всего, были вызваны работой антивируса. Проблема исчезла после добавления папки с исходниками в список исключения антивируса. Если это не помогает, то возможным решением может быть функция сброса буфера файла/потока `fflush()`, а именно в таком виде `fflush(stdin);` вызванная перед вторым вызовом `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char letter;
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter any one keyboard character: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    printf("Enter two integers separated by a space: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    printf("Numbers input: %d and %d \n", num1, num2);
    printf("Letter input: %c", letter);
    printf("Stored at: %p \n", &letter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В качестве дополнительного замечания - пробел в формате `scanf("%d %d"` является "лишним". Это не ошибка, но и смысла в нем никакого нет. Поведение формата `%d` уже само по себе включает в себя функциональность "пробела" (т.е. пропуск ведущих пробелов), поэтому явно запрашивать пропуск пробелов перед `%d` необходимости нет. Явный пробел в формате `scanf` может иметь смысл только перед спецификаторами `%c`, `%[]` и `%n`. Это, наверное, все. Уже сам факт использования пробела в этом месте говорит о том, что книгу писали методом копи-пейстинга. Отсюда и лишний пробел, и потерянные `&`...

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` - классика криво-кодинга. Стандартная билиотека С не разрешает применять `fflush` ко входным потокам (да, я знаю, что "POSIX разрешил", но в книге этому не место).

Comment: `fflush` в книге и нет. Это то, что я нагуглил в качестве средства против пропуска второго `scanf`. Да, костыль, но не-костыли не работали. Упомянул потому, что оно работало, когда остальное уже перепробовал и не помогло.

Comment: Это популярный "студенческий костыль" для решения этой прооблемы. Его вы и нагулили. В рамках же настоящего языка С: см. http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html и http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html . Это не так компактно, конечно, но тем не менее.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%c",letter);
scanf("%d %d", num1, num2);
```

следует вызывать как

```
scanf("%c",&letter);
scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
```

Нужно указывать *адрес* в памяти, куда записываются введенные данные

Comment: Текст программы построчно (да что уж там, посивольно) **скопирован** из книги. То есть ошибка явно в самой книге?

Comment: Совет помог, но теперь работает только первый вызов scanf. Второй не выводится, отрабатывая только printf

Comment: Вот, смотрите сами - все работает: http://ideone.com/zuNLbx Что до ошибок в книге... да, в книге нет & перед `letter`, но перед `num1` и `num2` определенно есть. Что в оригинале книги у автора - я не знаю, может, ошибка автора, может, при переводе потеряли...

Comment: Я рад, что у вас все получилось с онлайн-компилятором. А вот у меня ваш же код на моих компиляторах (обоих) отрабатывает [иначе](http://pastebin.com/nEUApAJj)

Comment: Вы точно вводите тот же код, что приведен в ideone? Вводите просто один символ и после него Enter? Ну чем я могу в данном случае помочь? Проверяйте у себя, попробуйте пройти отладчиком... Вряд ли вы дадите мне зайти к вам на машину и посмотреть, что там и как :) Этот код работает с gcc (в ideone), с Open Watcom, с Visual C++ 2015 (эти у меня на машине). Что творится у вас - я же не вижу.

Comment: Я скопировал ваш код напрямую. Компилирую gcc 5.4.0. Вывод можно посмотреть в pastebin по ссылке выше: отрабатывает только первый scanf

Comment: Нашел в справочнике функцию `fflush()` для сброса буфера потока. Применил как `fflush(stdin);` для очиски входящего потока после первого вызова scanf(). Все заработало. Однако я все равно не понимаю причин отличий поведения у меня и у вас.

Comment: @АнатолийГорбунов, кстати, из вашего пастебина видно, что ни один scanf не отрабатывает (в  введенный символ не печатается). А проверять, что возвращает scanf, это хорошая практика.